# Any two polish atomless probability spaces are isomorphic

Tags: probability-theory, descriptive-set-theory, geometric-measure-theory

On page 7 of Villani's *Optimal Transport: Old and New* (page 19 in [this preprint](http://cedricvillani.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/preprint-1.pdf)), he states that any two polish atomless probability spaces $(\mathcal{X},\mu)$ and $(\mathcal{Y},\nu)$ are measure-theoretically isomorphic and that, moreover, the isomorphism can be made from *all* of $\mathcal{X}$ to *all* of $\mathcal{Y}$ (not just *almost all* of each). **Where can I find a proof of this fact?**

In particular, I'm interested in the descriptive-set-theoretic complexity of such a map in a certain case.

Less importantly, he says

> Experience shows that it is quite easy to fall into logical traps when working with the measurable isomorphism, and my advice is to never use it.

**What logical traps is he talking about?**

Comment: I think that you should be able to find it in the books by Kechris or Moschovakis. The fact that any two uncountable Polish spaces have the same Borel $\sigma$-algebra is a classical result.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Halmos and von Neumann, see [this page](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Standard_probability_space) for references. Not sure they deal with the "descriptive-set-theoretic complexity" of such an isomorphism, though.

One could also check the references mentioned on [the obvious page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_probability_space).