# Its possible to construct i.i.d. random variables with the following property?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, reference-request

I want to know, via reference or explicit answer, if the following construction is possible: for a given probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),P)$, where $P$ there is any probability measure that we like, build a sequence $\{X_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of i.i.d. random variables such that $X_j:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ and $P=P\circ X^{-1}_j$ for every $j\in \mathbb{N}$.

UPDATE: in the book of Daniel W. Stroock about probability theory I found a positive answer if there exists an invertible random variable $X:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ with distribution $P$ such that $X^{-1}$ is also measurable.

The construction is, in short, of this kind: for any probability measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ we can construct a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $P$ from the probability space $([0,1], \mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda )$, where $\lambda $ is the Lebesgue measure.

Thus in the case that there exists such invertible random variable we can transform bijectively the measure space $([0,1],\mathcal{B}([0,1]), \lambda )$ in the measure space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}), P)$.

SECOND UPDATE: from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/539567/any-two-polish-atomless-probability-spaces-are-isomorphic) it seems that the construction holds for every atomless measure $P$.